# Service is not working -Android app is crashing

Tags: android, service, android-activity, manifest

I'm trying to make a simple app to test out the Services class. I want to have a button that when pressed starts a service and shows a Toast that the service has started, however, whenever I press the button the app crashes and I do not know what the problem is.
Testing Class:

```
public class ControllerTestingScreen extends Activity{

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_controller_test_screen);
    //Set button colors to red, green, blue, and red, respectively
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.testbutton);
    button.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xFFFF0000, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
    OnClickListener buttonListener = new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(),Controller.class));
            //sendSMS("PutPhoneNumberHereForTesting","WhereYouApp Text Message Test");
        }
    };
    button.setOnClickListener(buttonListener);
}
```

Manifest File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.whereyouapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<activity

         android:name="com.example.whereyouapp.ControllerTestingScreen"
         android:label="YOLO">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

     </activity>

      <service android:name="com.example.whereyouapp.Controller"/>
      </application>
</manifest>
```

Controller Class:

```
public class Controller extends Service{

private static final int POLL_INTERVAL = 1000 * 30;

public Controller(String name) {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent,int flags, int startId){
    Toast.makeText(this, "yololo- the service class works", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    return START_STICKY;
}

public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    Toast.makeText(this, "yolo- the service has stopped working", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


}

}
```

Error that I'm getting:

```
logcat error: 02-23 14:10:40.187: E/AndroidRuntime(1173): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service com.example.whereyouapp.Controller: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.example.whereyouapp.Controller; no empty constructor
```

Comment: Please post your stacktrace/error log .

Comment: I was testing it on my phone

Comment: Most likely because you cannot interact with the UI from a background thread.

Comment: @AnidMonsur There is no background thread!

Comment: Turn USB-debugging on and you'll see your logcat in you IDE.

Comment: Try replacing `getBaseContext()` with `this`

Comment: @Merlevede ill try it right now

Comment: @Merlevede thats not the problem

Comment: @user35265 post your logcat. save debug messages from usb debugging

Comment: logcat error:
02-23 14:10:40.187: E/AndroidRuntime(1173): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service com.example.whereyouapp.Controller: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.example.whereyouapp.Controller; no empty constructor

Comment: Please edit your question and include the full text of the error in the text, just as you would code.

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto did it

Comment: That's one line, please copy the whole thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your service does need parameterless constructor, if you define:

```
public Controller(String name)
```

then java will not automatically add parameter less one, and android needs it to instantiate your Service using `startService`

Comment: for the first contructor "The contructor String is undefined"

Comment: sorry, remove your constructors - its not an intent service

Comment: simply `public Controller()`, or remove all constructors

Answer (score 0):

I can't see `<application>` opening tag in your manifest O_o

Comment: what do you mean? Isn't it on there?

Comment: I'm not understanding to which part you are referring to because I see opening tag. Can you please elaborate more?

Comment: @user35265 the manifest that you've posted above, it has no `<application>` opening tag :) if you have it then it's okay :)